# Show that $e^{cx} \gt | P(x) |$ for some $c \gt 0$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, limits-without-lhopital

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial, and let $c > 0$. Show that there
exists a real number $N > 0$ such that $e^{cx} > |P(x)|$ for all $x > N$;

My work so far: $e^{cx}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{cx^n}{n!}$
and $|P(x)|=\sum_{n=0}^na_nx^n$

I would like to show that $e^{cx} - |P(x)| = \sum_{n=0}^{n} (\frac{c}{n!}-a_n) x^n > 0 $

I am not sure how to continue from here

Comment: [A slight variant of Kavi Rama Murthy's second proof, not worth posting as a separate answer.] If $f(x)$ is a non-constant monic polynomial, i.e., $f(x)=x^m+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}a_kx^k$, where $m\geqslant1$, then $x^{-m}f(x) = 1+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}a_kx^{k-m}\to1$ as $x\to\infty$, so $f(x)>0$ for all sufficiently large $x$. If $P(x)$ has degree $n$, then for either choice of sign, $e^{cx}\pm P(x)>\frac{(cx)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\pm P(x)$, which is a positive multiple of a non-constant monic polynomial, and is therefore positive for all sufficiently large $x$, so $e^{cx}>|P(x)|$ for all sufficiently large $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By repeated application of L'Hopital's Rule you can show that $\frac {p(x)} {e^{cx}} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. Hence there exists $N$ such that  $|\frac {p(x)} {e^{cx}}|<1$ for $x >N$.

Second proof: let $P(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N} a_ix^{i}$. From the series expansion of $e^{cx}$ we get $e^{cx} > \frac {c^{i+1}x^{i+1}} {(i+1)!}$. Hence $|c_ix^{i}| <  \frac 1 {cx} {(i+1)!} e^{cx}$. From this it is clear that there exists a positive number $M_i$ such that $|c_ix^{i}| < \frac 1 {N+1} e^{cx}$ for $x >M_i$. [ In fact it is enough to take $M_i >\frac {(i+1)!(N+1)} c$]. Now let $M$ be the maximum of the numbers $M_0,M_1,...,M_N$. Then $x >M%$ implies that each term in the polynomial is less than $\frac 1 {N+1} e^{cx}$ in absolute value. There are $N+1$ terms in the polynomial. Hence $|P(x)| <e^{cx}$ if $x >M$.

Comment: sorry for not stating this. But is it possible to get the result without using Lhopital's rule?

Comment: @Rico I have given hints for another proof. I can give more details if needed.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am considering how to do it. I will request more detail if I need it.

Comment: sorry I can not come up with the idea of proving this. Do you mind writing out the complete proof? Thank you so much.

Comment: @Rico I have given a detailed proof now.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I am now considering how to use this result to show that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{P(x)}{e^{cx}}=0$. From our result, it means that no matter how small $c$ we take, $e^{cx}$ will always be much bigger than $P(x)$ at a certain point. How may I incorporate these ideas and give a formal proof?

Comment: @Rico If $P(x)$ is a polynomial so is $xP(x)$. So there exists $N$ such that $|xP(x)| <e^{cx}$ for $x >N$. This gives $|P(x)|<\frac {e^{cx}} x$. Can you now show that $\frac {P(x)} {e^{cx}} \to 0$?.

Comment: Similarly, $|x^2 P(x)| < e^{cx}$ and repeat this idea we get $|P(x)| < \frac{e^{cx}}{x^n}$ for any $ n \in \Bbb N$. is this the correct continuation? Sorry I am still quite stuck.

Comment: No need to do that. Just use the fact that $\frac 1 x <\epsilon$ if $x$ is large enough.

Answer (score 1):

(Ignoring some errors in the indexes)

You have for $x>0;$ $e^{cx} - |P(x)| = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{c}{n!}-a_n) x^n \ge \sum_{n=0}^{\mbox{deg}(P)+1} (\frac{c}{n!}-a_n) x^n$ where $a_k=0$ for all $k>\mbox{deg}(P)$.

Now this is comparing polynomials